# How to access data from form validating controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I followed the tutorial for making a registration form with validation, with 2 views and 1 controller.

I wrote this in the controller:

```
function index()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[16]|xss_clean|callback_username_check');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[passconf]|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('register_form');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('register_success');

        $data = array(
        'IDUser' => NULL ,
        'Username' => "$username" ,         
        'Password' => 'password' ,
        'Email' => 'email' ,
        'Gender' => 'gender' ,
        'Birthday' => 'bday' ,
        );

        $this->db->insert('Accounts', $data);

    }


}
```

First it is executes a working sql insert. After, a validation. Nevertheless, the values loaded from the database are not those from the validation. Instead, they are the same plain text in the array.

I don't want to get the values directly from the form/view with POST; that's pointless. What do i do? I'm new to Codeigniter and not that familiar with OOP PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use Codeigniter Input class : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

So in your case:

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$passconf = $this->input->post('passconf');
$email    = $this->input->post('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

dragu is correct but please use this format:

```
 $username = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);
```

the TRUE tells codeigniter to XSS clean which is a security feature you definitely want. Thats also why you put XSS clean in the form validation. from yr example:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[16]|xss_clean|callback_username_check');
```

If the form fails validation, then CI can display the results in the form again. having xss_clean in the validation cleans those values.